# how twisted server detects an incomplete message

Tags: python, twisted

I am right now implementing a twisted client and twisted server. 
The question is how does the server detect if a message that is sent by client is completed?

For example, there are 2 clients sending messages to server, the message is a python list which has only several elements, respectively. The 2nd client sends the message very short time after the 1st client does.

Since it's async, the server will switch to serve the 2nd client, leaving the message of 1st client half-processed. So how do I do to let the server know this message is not complete? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to implement some sort of *protocol* (not to be confused with `twisted.internet.protocol`) which has some sort of delimiter signifying the beginning and end of a message and how long your message will be. For example, let's define a protocol which implements the following rules:

1. All messages start with `{`
2. An `int` number of bytes which will contain the message body, followed by `:`
3. The message body
4. An end tag `}`

An example expected message would look like:

```
{10:Hey Earth!}
```

Twisted provides many interfaces to do this for you, so you don't really have to do this on your own. There's [`LineReceiver`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html#helper-protocols) which combines bytes until a line break. There's the [AMP protocol](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/amp.html) and [`NetStrings`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.NetstringReceiver.html), which is similar to the example I provided previously.

### References:

- http://krondo.com/a-poetry-transformation-server/ - search for `netstring` you should find a good example of how to write one for yourself.

Comment: can I use a sync client to talk to this twisted server?

Comment: Absolutely. You can test it using Python's [``socket``](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rz5IF_Cxo4&list=PLats0B9d0gVV9hraFHVcCPj7HUg_dkPso&index=7) module and it will work fine.